Delete files from target folder, but keep the latest 50 files
I would like to create a batch file which should delete all files of a selected folder, but keep the latest 50 files, using Windows 10.
I found a similar code but this will be delete all files after 2 days, AutoDelete.bat:
ForFiles /p C:\Images\ /S /D -2 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"

Unfortunately, this doesn't suit me. I've tried searching for Forfiles commands, and I made some tests, but so far I haven't been successful.
How to delete files from a target folder, but keep the latest 50 files in Windows 10 batch?

That code doesn't do what you're telling us it does! It's clearly only iterating directories, and removing directories. The output from %SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /? and rd /? will tell you everything you need to know about that code, and may help you with your intended task. I say "may", because you have not explained what you mean by "latest". forfiles.exe only uses the most recently modified date and time stamp. That aside, your task, possibly with a different number of files, has been asked about, and answered, on multiple occasions before. Use the search facility.

If your task, as currently written, does not need to recurse subdirectories, then a one line batch file can do it, @For /F "Skip=50 EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "C:\Images" /A:-D /B /O:-D /T:W 2^>NUL') Do @Del "C:\Images\%%G" /A /F. That uses the Time Written, i.e. last modified, if you want the Time Created, change /T:W to /T:C instead. (You could also keep the 50 'oldest' by changing /O:-D to /O:D.)

Batch file
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Set the target folder path
set "folderPath=C:\Users\Josh\Downloads\test"

:: Create a temporary file to store the sorted list
set "tempfile=%temp%\sortedfiles.txt"

:: List files sorted by date, newest first
dir /B /A-D /O-D "%folderPath%\*.*" > "%tempfile%"

:: Count total files
set /a count=0
for /f %%A in ('type "%tempfile%"') do set /a count+=1

:: Display the latest 50 files
echo Latest 50 files that will be kept:
set /a current=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%tempfile%") do (
    set /a current+=1
    if !current! LEQ 50 (
        echo Keeping: %%A
    )
)

:: Show total count
echo.
echo Total files found: %count%
echo Latest 50 files will be preserved

:: Clean up temp file
del "%tempfile%"
pause

Remember to set your folderPath correctly.

If you can use a PowerShell script, then perhaps you can do this instead.
# Set the target folder path
$folderPath = “C:\Users\Josh\Downloads\test”

# Get all files in the folder, sort by last write time descending (newest first)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending

# Get the latest 50 files (these will be kept)
$latestFiles = $files | Select-Object -First 50

# Display the latest files that will be kept
Write-Host "Latest 50 files that will be kept:"
foreach ($file in $latestFiles) {
    Write-Host "Keeping: $($file.Name) - Last modified: $($file.LastWriteTime)"
}

# Calculate total files
Write-Host "`nTotal files found: $($files.Count)"
Write-Host "Latest 50 files will be preserved"


The code used by the OP, whilst their task description does not specify it, is recursing C:\Images. As your examples above are not recursing subdirectories, perhaps you'd have been better advised to get clarification before submitting an answer. Additionally, as there was no mention of PowerShell, and no tag for it, I have made a change to your off topic code .

Noted. I will keep that in mind moving forward.
